# How do to show consideration for other language visitors on your web page?

Tags: html, translation, lang

How do to show consideration for other language visitors on your web page?

For example, if a page is in English and you speak another language maybe some English or no English what would you want to see? I'm guessing provide the language translation in your own language (but maybe don't do that because then translation services may not work).

This is not an opinion based question because we have language specifications [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/) and we have Google Translate built into Chrome. I'm asking as a developer what do you do and as a visitor of a site not in the same language what would you like or expect or suggest developer not do (again, "don't x because it will break Google Translate").

Comment: What are you looking for here? How to gracefully guide users to other language options?  How to dynamically serve content of various languages? Or how to design a site for consumption by users who may not speak the language it is written in? I would generally recommend checking the [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) HTTP header and serving the correlating version of the content, but I'm not sure if this is the kind of answer you're looking for here. Otherwise, you can have language versioned subdomains or URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide any kind of content in an alternative language, I suggest it's not generated automatically.

I've worked in multi-language websites before. You usually have a team of professional translators generating contents in a different language, and use a content management system that supports per-page language translation; then you choose the method for determining the user's language: cookies, sessions, browser language, you let the user choose from a language selector, or you have completely independent domains the user is eventually redirected to.

You can also use JavaScript libraries to auto-translate the page based on the user's browser language. In my experience, these translations are always sub-par to what Google translate offers, and even worse than showing your website in a language that the user doesn't know, is showing badly-translated content in the user's native language: Your users will think that either the webmaster is not professional enough to get a proper translation or they may even think the writer has mental issues.

Whatever you do, don't insult your user's intelligence. You either provide valuable content in their native language or you don't. That shows that your brand has integrity.